# How to inject the variable in the abstract class while unit testing the subclass?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have an abstract class `BaseTemplate` and multiple classes extending it. In one of the concrete class(`SmsTemplate extends BaseTemplate`), we have a private variable `Gson`. We have the same private variable(`Gson`) in the abstract class as well.

While unit tesing the concrete class, methods in the abstract class is getting called from the concrete class. In my Unit test, I am using `Whitebox.setInternalState(smsTemplateObj, gsonObj);` to inject the Gson object into the private members of `SmsTemplate` and `BaseTemplate` but the Gson is getting injected only in the subclass. In abstract class, its `NULL`, meaning not injected. Below is the implementation.

Can someone please tell how to inject the Gson object in the abstract class?

```
abstract class BaseTemplate{

    private Gson gson;//Here its not getting injected

    protected String getContent(Content content){
        return gson.toJson(content); // ERROR - gson here throws NPE as its not injected
    }
}

class SmsTemplate extends BaseTemplate{

    private Gson gson;//Here its getting injected

    public String processTemplate(Content content){
        String strContent = getContent(content);
        ...
        ...
        gson.fromJson(strContent, Template.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the field of the abstract class protected and remove the remove the field from the subclass.

Comment: @Stefan - Ahh... the problem is, the Gson object is not used in all the concrete classes.

Comment: Why do you need a gson variable in the abstract class AND the subclass?

Comment: @bryce - in both abstract and subclass(not in all subclasses), gson object is obviously needed.

Comment: If the Gson object is not needed in all concrete classes, you need a second level of abstraction. BaseTemplate without Gson an abstract class that extends BaseTemplate and in this one the Gson object. The concrete class that don't need the Gson object extend BaseTemplate and the others extend your second abstracclass

Comment: @bryce - i like the 2nd level of abstraction. Is there any another approach to unit test without 2nd abstraction?

Comment: Provide a setter method in BaseTemplate where you can set the gson explicitely? Though, bad smell to include a method just for unit-testing an unlucky design. Also note, that in its current form, every child element of BaseTemplate will have its own private `gson` member (even if you kind of "shadowing" it later with concrete implementations) which is set to null for children not needing this field at all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Whitebox.setInternalState()` method will only set the value of the first field it encounters going up through the hierarchy of the object you pass. So once it finds `gson` field in your subclass, it won't look further and won't change the superclass field.

There are two solutions for this case:

- **Change the variables names.** If the variables have different names, you can simply invoke `Whitebox.setInternalState()` twice, one for each variable.
- **Set the field manually using reflection.** You can also just set the field without Mockito's help using something like the following snippet.

Snippet:

```
Field field = smsTemplateObj.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("gson");
field.setAccesible(true);
field.set(smsTemplateObj, gsonObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a second abstraction layer:

```
abstract class BaseTemplate{

    // private Gson gson;// no Gson here

    protected String getContent(Content content){
        // do what you want without Gson
    }
}

abstract class BaseTemplateWithGson extends BaseTemplate{

    protected Gson gson;

    @Override
    protected String getContent(Content content){
        return gson.toJson(content);
    }
}

class SmsTemplate extends BaseTemplateWithGson {

    public String processTemplate(Content content){
        String strContent = getContent(content);
        ...
        ...
        gson.fromJson(strContent, Template.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: i like the 2nd level of abstraction. Is there any another approach to unit test without 2nd abstraction?

Comment: For me there is not a problem of unit testing but of desing... When it is hard to unit test something, ask for a design problem ;-)

Comment: Can you please tell what is the design issue in the implementation?

Comment: The problem is to have an attribute Gson in the parent abstract class if some of the subclasses don't need it...

Comment: The attribute in the parent class is only private, not accessible to the subclasses which don't need it.

Comment: you are right but it still not accessible for the subclasses who need it too ;-)