# Mock and Inject inherited fields

Tags: java, unit-testing, inheritance, junit, mockito

I am having problems with inheritance and writing Unit-Tests. I don't know how to inject a mock as a field, when my class I want to test inherits this field. Note that I can't stub anything, since the test-class is an extra Test-package. I just want to get the `myService.getSomething()`-call working.

```
    public class A{
    @Autowired
    private Service myService;

    protected void doSomething(){
        //
        someValue = myService.getSomething();
    }
```

And Class B, which inherits the methods:

```
    public class B extends A{
        public void someMethod(){
            doSomething();
        }
    }
```

And this would be my Testclass:

```
public class TestB{
        @Mock
        private Service myService;

        @InjectMocks
        private B classUnderTest = new B();

        @Before
        public void setUp(){
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }

        @Test
        public void testSomeMethod(){
            SomeValue someValue = new SomeValue();
            doReturn(someValue).when(myService).getSomething();

            classUnderTest.doSomething();
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would recommend you to override the method in the child and call the fathers method inside.

Comment: The problem is not the `doSomething()` call of class A, it's `myService`

Comment: Create a setter for yourService in the Father and overwrite it on your child.
The Setters in Spring could be `@Autowired` .
Or create an ´@Autowired´ constructor in the father and other in the Child, and call the Fathers. After that inject your mocked dependency.

Comment: This might help: http://lkrnac.net/blog/2014/01/mock-autowired-fields/

Answer (score 6):

One possible approach is to use java reflection to set/change the fields in runtime:

```
    Field parentService = classUnderTest.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("myService");
    parentService.setAccessible(true);
    parentService.set(classUnderTest, myService_mock);
```

Was looking for the solution as well and this worked for me.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31832491/2489388

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. By using reflection i was able to inject mocked object on parent class. Below is a code snipper.
EmailApiHandler is the child class that was extending APIHandlerBase.java and loginService and mailerService was declared in parent base class i.e APIHandlerBase.java. I was mocking EmailApiHandler.java and used below method.

```
@Before public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    Field loginService = null;
    Field mailerService = null;
    try {
        loginService = EmailApiHandler.class.getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("loginService");
        loginService.setAccessible(true);
        loginService.set(handler, loginService);
        mailerService = EmailApiHandler.class.getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mailerService");
        mailerService.setAccessible(true);
        mailerService.set(handler, mailer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } }
```